# why perl -e "print lc "Hello-World\n"" prints 0

Tags: bash, macos, perl

I have a code that I want to debug with perl's `-e` option from the command line. *(from a Mac OS terminal, to be exact)*

When I called a subroutine like that, I forgot to correctly match the double quote marks, kinda like that:

```
perl -e "print lc "Hello-World\n""
#Output: 0
```

I was surprised to see `0` but, after looking closer, I saw that I had a problem with my double quote marks. Unsurprisingly, using outer single quote marks fixes the issue

```
perl -e 'print lc "Hello-World\n"'
# Output(fixed): hello-world
```

And now that I saw what the problem was, I am intrigued to see that it returned `0` in the first place. It looks like bash performed some kind of subtraction operation because if I repeat the same mistake by not having a dash there, I don't have that issue even with wrong double quote marks:

```
perl -e "print lc "HelloWorld\n""
                  ^ closing the quotes too soon
#Output: helloworldn
```

So why is it that this syntax `perl -e "print lc "Hello-World\n""` prints 0?

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't want ot spend time on it. Deleted my 2nd comment and will delete this shortly. Good luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a useful trick to find out what perl is 'thinking'.

run `perl -MO=Deparse -e "print lc "Hello-World\n""`

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e "print lc "Hello-World\n""
print lc 'Hello' - 'Worldn';
-e syntax OK
```

What's happening here is that `perl` is "seeing" `Hello - Worldn` as an arithmetic sum. And because the strings are numerically zero, you're printing `0-0`. It's nothing to do with `bash`, but rather with `perl` and how it treats numeric values.

This is because barewords are acceptable if you're not using `strict` and `warnings`, but are coerced to numeric values by the subtraction (e.g. 0)

If you had turned on `warnings`:

```
perl -Mwarnings -e "print lc "Hello-World\n""
Argument "Worldn" isn't numeric in subtraction (-) at -e line 1.
Argument "Hello" isn't numeric in subtraction (-) at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 4):

The following can be useful to see code parsed by perl:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e "print lc "Hello-World\n""
print lc 'Hello' - 'Worldn';
```

And `'Hello'` and `'Worldn'` converted as int is 0.

Comment: This really is useful. +1 - but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: Why this doesn't answer to the question, the accepted answer is telling the same thing

Comment: It's more than "same thing". It elaborates on why hello is converted to 0. It explains why I mistakenly thought it to be a bash behavior and how it's actually just per. It also introduced the keyword "bareword" and added the warnings details as well. See - for a newbie in Perl such details make the difference between a copy paste answer or an understood one

Answer (score 2):

Inside a one-liner I tend to use [generalized quotes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) to avoid these problems:

```
$ perl -e "print lc qq(Hello-World\n)"
```

If the double quotes are there just for the newline, you can use the `-l` switch to add a newline to every `print` (but not `printf`):

```
$ perl -le "print lc 'Hello-World'"
```

With `-E` you can turn on v5.10 features, including `say`, which also adds a newline to the output:

```
$ perl -E "say lc 'Hello-World'"
```

You've tagged this as `macOS`, which means that you can use single quotes for the argument to `-e` (Windows does not allow that):

```
$ perl -e 'print lc qq(Hello-World\n)'
$ perl -e 'print lc "Hello-World\n"'
```

Inside the double quotes on a Unix like shell, things that start with `$` are variables. This fails because the shell interpolates `$HOME` before Perl even sees the program string (it's `print /Users/brian`). This is a silly example but it shows the problem:

```
 $ perl -le "print $HOME"
 Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at -e line 1, at end of line
 Unknown regexp modifier "/r" at -e line 1, at end of line
-e had compilation errors.
```

Either escape the `$` or use single quotes:

```
 $ perl -le "print \$HOME"
 $ perl -le 'print  $HOME'
```